# Axon - Auto Create Tables, Is there a way to indicate specific schema for them

Tags: axon

[image]

I´m starting using Axon with Spring boot, but I see the this table are created in the same schema where I have the business tables, Is there any way to indicate that these tables to be in other schema?

Comment: Do you find solution @Israel Rz ,if yes please share solution

Answer (score 0):

Axon uses a container-provided `EntityManagerProvider` by default. You can see this in the `JpaAutoConfiguration` class. By creating your own bean, with your own EntityManager bound to another schema, you can customize this.

This would look like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerProvider entityManagerProvider(
            @Qualifier("axonEntityManager") EntityManager axonEntityManager) {
        return new SimpleEntityManagerProvider(axonEntityManager);
    }

    @Bean(name = "axonEntityManager")
    public EntityManager axonEntityManager() {
        // Create an entity manager with custom schema here
        return someEntityManager;
    }

}
```